# Eclipse Debugger Not working. Weird breakpoint

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been using Eclipse for a while now, and up to about a week ago the debugger has been working fine. However, now it does not run in the debug mode, but as if I just pressed run. Also, my breakpoints look different and have small black arrows on them. I tried reinstalled eclipse, but that did not work. This is what the breakpoints look like now. I am using jdk 1.8.0_172.

These are some of the breakpoints:

[image: The breakpoint]

[image: Another breakpoint]

Comment: Seems not in [the list](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm)

Comment: Which version of Eclipse is it? What plugins do you have installed?

Answer (score 1):

These are ***Triggers for breakpoints***.

For details:

- See [Eclipse 4.7 - New and Noteworthy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/jdt.php#triggers-for-breakpoints)
- Watch [my short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0-cO9wZj6w&t=431s)

Comment: Thank you, I the first linked help me figure it out. I had to change enable trigger point. Not to sure why that mattered that much.